PM2 command automation, how to manage permission
I installed node.js and npm on my Win server.
But i have problems with pm2.
I wanna automate the function of the PM2, so when the machine is restarted a Scheduled task resurrect PM2 status and restart my daemon.
It seems work, but from Command line i cannot see the daemon from PM2 list command.
If i run manually my bat file it work correctly and i see everything.
I suppose is something from the user that is used from the scheduled task.
Any suggestion?
How can i solve this?
I want to restore the daemon automatically when the machine is restarted.

There is on npm many package that can help you install PM2 as a windows service. This one for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@davistran86/pm2-windows-service
Just install the package with: npm i pm2-windows-service -g
Then install the service: pm2-service-install -n "My PM2 service name".
If you want to uninstall the  service: pm2-service-uninstall
Then when service is installed, if you update the some process , don't forget to to issue pm2 save to save the PM2 configuration.

I manage to do in this way:
Inside the Startup Common folder (the global one, used for all users on the system: shell:common startup) i add a link to my batch file.
My Batch file is structured this way:
@echo off
call pm2 resurrect || echo "Resurrect failed, continuing..."
echo Resurrect WebSocket
call pm2 restart all

I see that pm2 resurrect restore the last snapshot saved for the pm2 state.
In my case the state was saved after the first installation, so i only need the restore if the machine is restarted, i don't need a script to launch all for the first time.
I don't know if it's the correct solution, but for my case it works.

The best solution is installing pm2 as a windows service.
See my response.
